# Deploy .NET Core docker container to Azure with nugets in local fileshare

Tags: c#, azure, docker, .net-core, nuget

we have an on-premise instance of Azure Pipelines through which I am trying to build a .NET Core application and build a docker container for it. We have done this in the past, but I am quite new to docker and azure pipelines and I'm running into an issue where the `dotnet restore` command inside the container is failing because it can't find our local packages. We have our internal NuGet packages stored on a network share, but I am unsure how to create my configuration so that it can pick up these packages.

This is how our .yaml file stages looks like when not using local packages:

```
stages:
  - stage: "CI"
    pool: AppDev
    jobs:
    - job: buildAndTest
      workspace:
        clean: all
      steps:
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 3.1.100'
        inputs:
          version: 3.1.301
          includePreviewVersions: false    
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'dotnet restore'
        inputs:
          command: restore
          projects: '**/*.sln'
          selectOrConfig: config
          nugetConfigPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Nuget.config
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'dotnet build'
        inputs:
          projects: '**/*.sln'
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'dotnet test'
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: '**/*Test*.csproj'
          testRunTitle: 'Testrun'
  - stage: "BuildDockerImage"
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
    condition: or(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'),eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    jobs:
      - job: buildImageRelease
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
        steps:
        - task: Docker@2
          inputs:
            containerRegistry: DockerImageRepo
            repository: $(dockerimage)
            buildContext: src
            tags: $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Contacts/contacts.csproj", "Contacts/"]
COPY ["Contracts/Contracts.csproj", "Contracts/"]
COPY ["Handlers/Handlers.csproj", "Handlers/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Contacts/contacts.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Contacts"
RUN dotnet build "contacts.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "contacts.csproj" -r linux-musl-x64 --self-contained true -c Release /p:PublishTrimmed=true -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["./contacts", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80"]
```

As you can suspect, the docker task is failing at the `dotnet restore` line.

I was thinking of mounting the network share as a volume and then adding the nuget package source but I can't wrap my head around as to how to do this.

Comment: Yeah its a pain to get nugets to restore from a local and private authenticated nuget feeds inside a docker file, among many other complexities that arises with pipelines builds and containers. Personally, in all my pipelines I build in the pipeline itself and copy, no fuss, drastically simplified docker files, and years added back to my life

Comment: @TheGeneral that does sound like the most simple solution... I would only have to add a dotnet publish step and then in my dockerfile do a copy of that output, right?

Comment: You could even do the publish in the pipeline what ever you need to do, and just copy the resulting directory exactly where it needs to go. E.g `COPY bin/Release/net5.0/ubuntu.18.04-x64 /app` assuming your docker file is in your project

Comment: Sorry I misread your comment, yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the pkg and nuget.config into the image when build

```
COPY ["mypackage.nupkg", "/packages"]
COPY nuget.config .
```

The content of the nuget.config must be equivalent to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="local" value="./packages" />
    </packageSources>
    
</configuration>
```

See [Microsoft NuGet.config File Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)